# how to add image next to the contact form 7 do not have space between image and contact form

Tags: css, wordpress

*How to add image next to the contact form 7 in the same line. I am trying to add but image is showing under contact form help

I want to looks like this:
[image]

Anybody to help me please

Comment: Please add some relevant code ...add a fiddle

Comment: <a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo-temno.png"><img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-128 alignbaseline" style="vertical-align:baseline;" alt="logo temno" src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo-temno-150x150.png" width="150" height="150" /></a>

<center>
[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Untitled"]</center>

Comment: I am trying on this way, I like the contact form and the image be like one

Answer (score 0):

css code 
position : absolute
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: When the poster's question is of such poor form, best to ask them for more advice rather then guess at an answer.  If you understand what they mean, then please expand upon it in your answer (in situations like these)

Comment: he just wants a image be next to contact form 7, so in page contents [contactform_shortcode] <img style="position: ..... (I thought it was already pretty clear)